# Is every finite field of the form $GF(p^2)$ isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I heard that finite fields are either $GF(p)$, or $GF(p^k)$, with $p$ prime and $k > 1$. One obtains a $GF(p^k)$ through an algebraic quotient of polynomials over $GF(p)$; the polynomial ideal used in the quotient should itself be based on an irreducible polynomial. For $k = 2$, the irreducible polynomials are of the form $X^2 - r$, which can be reduced to $X^2 + 1$; and we get spaces isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[i]$. But I was wondering if $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[j]$, with $j^2 = 1$ like the split-complex numbers, were also a (different) solution, with $X^2 - 1$ as the generator for the ideal. If not, why not?

Comment: Try with $p=5$, is $X^2+1$ irreducible

Comment: Also, with $p=2$, is anything of the form $X^2 - r$ irreducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concretely: for $f\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ irreducible then $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$ is an integral domain with $p^{\deg(f)}$ elements, thus it is a field with $p^{\deg(f)}$ elements. All such fields with $p^{\deg(f)}$ elements are a splitting field of $x^{p^{\deg(f)}}-x\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$, they are isomorphic, so we can consider the field with $p^{\deg(f)}$ elements as being unique.

For your question: it remains to find an **irreducible** polynomial of degree $2$.

Comment: I'm unsure as to how I can find whether polynomials over finite fields are irreducible. From Wikipedia :
"the polynomial X^2 − r is irreducible over GF(p) if and only if r is a quadratic non-residue modulo p"
So as I understand, quadratic residue modulo p play a role, but I'm clueless as to what they are.

Comment: Yes in general it is not immediate to find a quadratic non-residue. When $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$ we can take $-1$, when $p\equiv 2\bmod 5$ we can take $5$, and so on, but there are infinitely many other primes. And for $p=2$ there are none, we need to take $f=x^2+x+1$.

Comment: So then, $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[j]$ would be a field iff $1$ is a quadratic non residue modulo $p$; and $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[i]$, is a finite field iff $-1$ is a quadratic non residue mod $p$ ? Very interesting question and answer, thanks !

Comment: quadratic **non** residue (ie. never for $1$ and $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$ for $-1$) @TristanDuquesne

Comment: Oof, yeah, edited that, thanks.

Comment: 1 is never a quadratic nonresidue (no matter $p$). So $X^2-1$ is never an irreducible polynomial for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, so $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[j]$ is never a field. In addition $-1$ is a quadratic nonresidue iff $p \not\equiv 1 [mod ; 4]$, so iff $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, p \neq 4n+1$. So for example, $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are fields, but not $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: Finally, there are a lot of fields of the form $GF(p^2)$, which are not isomorphic to some $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[i]$, since you can pick a quadratic nonresidue $\neq -1$ in many cases. This thoroughly answers my question, thank you